Android studio won't allow devices to be viewed due to adb not being found and windows c runtime not being installed windows 8 pro
I have been trying to run an application in android studio but the engine can't trace adb due to windows c runtime not being installed
I tried to update windows but the update wasn't being found I also tried reinstalling SDK platform tools but it failed to work.
